# What kind of creature is Captain Kalaw in Freedom Planet 2

Tags: freedom-planet

In the *Freedom Planet 2* video game, we only ever see Captain Kalaw the Red Wing of Justice wearing his characteristic red armor.  What kind of creature is he under that armor?  Is he birdfolk?  Another half-dragon?

I'd like an authoritive statement: preferably dialog or text from the game itself, or a statement by the publishers.

[image]

Comment: Rufous Hornbill is the common statement, in part due to that "Kalaw" is the Phillipine name for that species.

Answer (score 11):

It falls short of being entirely authoritative, but Captain Kalaw is from the Phillipines expy, Parusa, and "Kalaw" is the term used in the Phillipines for the Rufous Hornbill, whose head resembles the armor helmet.

[image: Image of the Rufous Hornbill]

Comment: Surely you mean *"It falls short of being **in any way** authoritative"*

Comment: Hmm... I tried tagging [@GalaxyTrail](https://twitter.com/galaxytrail) with the question, but I can't find it now.